# How to monitor MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, logging

Say I browse a php page, how do I know what database queries are run?
I think if I can log all the queries to a .txt file that would solve my problem. I tried to log, but failed. I just want to know the queries (sql strings) sent to it.

I'm using WinXP and Apache.

Comment: what you want to know??? where is code??

Comment: @diEcho code is not relevant, he wants to see the query log

Comment: @Ben: [edit] not comment

Comment: @WesleyMurch Fair point, usually would...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

just copy and paste the string in `mysql_query()` into an echo just before the query.

Comment: because this is kind of manually way, can be use only when you typing those codes, can not use it for some large existing code where you need to know which queries has run. Also mysql already has a configuration for this.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it is going into your my.cnf configuration file and activate the general log. As hinted is a performance killer, so never activate it in production. For development is perfectly OK, though. On my laptop is on all the time.

```
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

Comment: Once this configuration is done, a mysql restart is required.

Or, as it's mentioned, you can temporarily enable the log at runtime: Just run the mysql query: "SET global general_log = 'ON';" Then your general_log_file will log all queries.

Answer (score 0):

Find your mysql log files directory  - mine was:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data
```

Look for the last updated file.  Should be NAME OF YOUR COMPUTER.log - that will be your default logfile ** - Mysql is generally shipped with basic logging enabled, IIRC.

Else, as has been said, set up logging in your cnf file and restart the Mysql service.

** Make yourself a shortcut to this file on your desktop, you should be looking at it often.

When the file gets too big, delete it and restart the Mysql service and it'll start a new one with the same name.

Comment: mine mysql5.1 — I can not find the  dir named "data"

Comment: Searching your hdd for a folder called /data could be long and slow.